# nginx proxy to wordpress

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I'm trying to make nginx proxy www.hostname.com/blog to another server running wordpress.

I tried this configuration but I'm not having success:

```
location ~ ^/blog(/?)(.*) {
    proxy_pass http://104.131.199.80/$1$is_args$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

When I request `www.hostname.com/blog` the page opens as it should, but when I request `www.hostname.com/blog/anything` I get a redirect to `104.131.199.80/blog/anything`.

Any idea of what can be causing this?

Comment: This sounds normal. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I don't want to get a redirect to the IP address

Comment: Then you need to fix your WordPress settings.